# startup_name_generator depends on flutter_icons from unknown source "image_path", version solving failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image

CODE:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MRki.png

flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

flutter_icons:

image_path_android: "assets/images/technology.png"

image_path_ios: "assets/images/technology.png"

android: true

ios: true

ERROR:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xlwo.png

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) package documentation, you have to write the image_path & android & iOS and assign specific value to it.

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```